# Javascript combine ArrayBuffer parts

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays, typedarray, uint8array

I need to combine 2 parts of 2 existing arrayBuffers into a new one.

I am building a parser and the data comes in arraybuffers of random sizes, the data will spill over the end of one, into the beginning of the other. So I need to create a new output buffer and copy in a portion of the end of one buffer and a portion of the beginning of the other. The output will just be an Arraybuffer.

Starting out with this demo, I was going to make Uint8Arrays with some offsets then use set, the problem is certain combinations throw `Invalid typed array length`. I will not know the length of each array or offsets beforehand.

```
var buffer1 = new ArrayBuffer(8);
var buffer2 = new ArrayBuffer(8);
var buffer3 = new ArrayBuffer(8);

var uint8_1 = new Uint8Array(buffer1);
var uint8_2 = new Uint8Array(buffer2);
var uint8_3 = new Uint8Array(buffer3);

uint8_1.fill(1);
uint8_2.fill(2);

var uint8_1_slice = new Uint8Array(buffer1 , 0 , 3);
var uint8_2_slice = new Uint8Array(buffer2 , 4, 7);
```

For this demo need to get buffer3 to be 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2.

> Cannot Use Slice

Answer (score 4):

I have seen some people only use `array.length`. It's fine as long as the array is only 1 byte per element. It's also fine if the other typed arrays are filled up but in this example `a2` isn't. That is why it's better to use `byteLength` this is also how Blob constructor concatenate the parts.

```
// Concatenate a mix of typed arrays
function concatenate(...arrays) {
  // Calculate byteSize from all arrays
  let size = arrays.reduce((a,b) => a + b.byteLength, 0)
  // Allcolate a new buffer
  let result = new Uint8Array(size)

  // Build the new array
  let offset = 0
  for (let arr of arrays) {
    result.set(arr, offset)
    offset += arr.byteLength
  }

  return result
}

// the total length of 1-3 = 5
// the total byteLength of 1-3 = 6
let a1 = Uint8Array.of(1, 2) // [1, 2]
let a2 = Uint16Array.of(3) // [3] just for the fun of it 16 takes up 2 bytes
let a3 = Uint8Array.of(4, 5) // [4, 5]

concatenate(a1, a2, a3) // [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5]

/********/
var blob = new Blob([a1, a2, a3])
var res = new Response(blob)
res.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => console.log(new Uint8Array(buffer)))
// [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Note: This `concatenate` function only supports Uint8Array arguments. For example, `concatenate(new Uint16Array([1,2,3]))` returns [ 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0 ] rather than [ 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0 ]. The problem is that Uint8Array.set() iterates over the *elements* of the given typed array rather than the bytes. The solution is to change `result.set(arr, offset)` to `result.set(new Uint8Array(arr.buffer, arr.byteOffset, arr.byteLength), offset)`. (Note that support for ArrayBuffer arguments would require additional logic.)

Answer (score 1):

> For this demo need to get buffer3 to be 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2.

You can use `for` loop, set `uint8_3` to `uint8_1` value if variable `n` is less than `uint8_1.byteLength / 2` else set `uint8_3` to value at `uint8_2` .

```js
var len = 8;

var buffer1 = new ArrayBuffer(len);
var buffer2 = new ArrayBuffer(len);
var buffer3 = new ArrayBuffer(len);

var uint8_1 = new Uint8Array(buffer1);
var uint8_2 = new Uint8Array(buffer2);
var uint8_3 = new Uint8Array(buffer3);

uint8_1.fill(1);
uint8_2.fill(2);
// `len` : uint8_1.byteLength / 2 + uint8_2.byteLength / 2
for (var n = 0; n < len; n++) {
  uint8_3[n] = n < len / 2 ? uint8_1[n] : uint8_2[n];
}

console.log(uint8_3);
```

Comment: This is on the right track, It should use set though because if not you're copying 1 byte at a time.

Comment: Actually sorry, can't use slice, it will return a new array.

Comment: @brianxautumn _"Actually sorry, can't use slice, it will return a new array"_ Not sure what you mean? Is requirement to not create a new array?

Comment: Yes, speed and memory usage are very, very important in this case.

Comment: Better, but the problem is that it is copying 1 byte at a time, when it could be copying up to 8 at a time.

Comment: @brianxautumn _"Better, but the problem is that it is copying 1 byte at a time, when it could be copying up to 8 at a time."_ Yes, requirement was to not use `.slice()` "can't use slice it will return a new array"?  [`.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set) does not expect a third parameter. [`.subarray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/subarray) also returns a new array.

Comment: @brianxautumn Do you want to remove the values from the two existing typed arrays?